# MBP connects to WiFi but not to internet

Tags: network

This happens periodically, but I still don’t know why....very frustrating.
2011 MacBook Pro, High Sierra 10.13.5. 10 other devices in the house using WiFi no problem, between Galaxy S9, 3 iPads, an HP laptop and numerous smart TVs.... this has happened at home as well as on the road and I know that it is my MBP, but usually I manage to fix it- not this time. Have reset both SMC and PRAM. Have deleted WiFi service and re-added it. Have manually entered IPv4 addresses and DNS servers. Probably did some other things that I don’t remember anymore...

Restarted numerous times. Don’t know what to do anymore... usually it comes back by now, but no such luck. What else can I try?  I have even been in Terminal running some commands to try to clear my caches etc...When I ping a DNS server in Terminal like Google’s, 8.8.8.8, I get responses, but I have to manually set my IPv4 address and subnet mask to 255.255.255.0. When everything is configured like normal, i.e. IPv4 using DHCP and IPv6 configured automatically, I do not have a self-assigned IP address, but it does show me having an IPv6 address, which is weird and don’t recall seeing that before, usually it is an IPv4 address. When I get my IP address in terminal, it is not a class C, starting in 192, but rather a class B starting with 169 and the subnet mask is then 255.255.0.0, which I never see.

I also cannot boot into Safe mode for some reason. When i get to the logo screen and the progress bar underneath, the progress bar gets halfway and then the screen goes dark and it powers off. I can boot into recovery mode and if I use the Get Help Online section and open Safari, I GET ON THE INTERNET JUST FINE.... so what the heck gives?? Doesn’t make any sense... Please help...
Thank you!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79889/discussion-on-question-by-manfred33-mbp-connects-to-wifi-but-not-to-internet).

Comment: Can’t reply in chat now for some reason. Am on my iPad, which is what I have been using... have reloaded the page numerous times.  @JBis

Comment: When I try to send my message, the “send” button goes from blue to grey but nothing happens...

Comment: Manfred might need to find one answer somewhere that someone can upvote if chat isn’t working.

Comment: Yeah, I don’t know why it’s not working now, was working fine all this time...

Comment: I should add, that my description of using the send button is on the full site... on the mobile site, I tap on the blue button with white airplane and it does nothing, doesn’t change color etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking in a chat with the OP. I suggested the following solution, which in the end solved the issue.

---

Follow [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) to reinstall macOS:

> ### Start up from macOS Recovery
>
> 1. macOS Recovery installs different versions of macOS depending on the key combination you use while starting up. Turn on or restart your
>      Mac, then immediately hold down one of these combinations:
>      [image]
>
> 2.Release the keys when you see the Apple logo or a spinning globe.
>
> ### Install macOS
>
> 1. Choose Reinstall macOS (or Reinstall OS X) from the utilities window.
> 2. Click Continue, then follow the onscreen instructions. You'll be asked to select your disk. If you don't see it, click Show All Disks.
> 3. Click Install. Your Mac restarts after installation is complete.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.... Fortunately I was able to use the Internet in Recovery Mode to download and reinstall High Sierra, which made it all the more weird that I could not use the internet there but not when I booted normally.

Comment: @Manfred33 Yup. Kind of odd that it worked in recovery and not normal boot. Please make sure to upvote answer by clicking the uparrow to the left of the answer.